# How to add style to a class programmatically - Angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, ng-class

In my application I am using a library which has not exposed its elements.
I can only use it via it's selector.

I am overriding its css by using `>>>`. for example:

`>>> .wrapper{
  top: 0px !important;
  width: 400px !important;
}`

Now I want to add a new class `temp-wrapper` and in this class I want to add `width: 100px !important`.

I am able to add it by using `classList.add('temp-wrapper')`.

But problem is that width value is coming from another component when some event occurs. Is their any way by which I append some styles to a particular class in runtime.

Also I have used `ngStyle` and its not working as I have to use `>>>` in front of class name in order to override.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a style element dynamically, put the css definations and add the component do document, eg:

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.id = "myStyleId" // so later you can track and update easily
var css = ".temp-wrapper { backdround-color: red; border: 1px solid blue; .......}";
style.innerHTML = css;
document.head.append(style);
```

In case you don't want to apply some inline style and want to add some class and 
want to create the class defination dynamicall

Comment: in this case what would be the class name. I need to add `>>>` in front of class name on order to acheive overriding

Comment: everything will go inside variable css, whatever css you want to write.

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you meant by `>>>`, I have edited my answer and added class name so you can add classes dynamically to style. if you want to override some style use `!important` flag for that particular style in class.